# Cannot create JHipster application (error in ng plugin)

Tags: gulp, jhipster

I appreciate this is probably not a JHipster specific issue, but how some of my dependencies may be installed. It happens on 3.0.0 and 3.1.0. On the other hand 2.27.0 is fine.

This happens when I run `yo jhipster`.

```
...

Server app generated successfully.

Client app generated successfully.

(node:38364) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[21:00:11] Using gulpfile ~/dev/projects/blog/gulpfile.js
[21:00:11] Starting 'install'...
[21:00:11] Starting 'wiredep:test'...
[21:00:11] Starting 'wiredep:app'...
[21:00:11] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[21:00:11] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 12 ms
[21:00:11] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1324:5)
    at getFilePath (/Users/me/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:95:27)
    at DestroyableTransform.objectStream [as _transform] (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:60:25)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:352:10)
    at ngConstantPlugin (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/gulp-ng-constant-fork/index.js:33:16)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/gulpfile.js:164:12)
    at module.exports (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/alberto/dev/projects/blog/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
```

Then when I start the application I get this on the browser's console:

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blogApp due to:
       Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'blogApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/nomod?p0=badgeritoApp
        at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
        at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2034:17
        at ensure (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1958:38)
        at module (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2032:14)
        at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4524:22
        at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:20)
        at loadModules (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4508:5)
        at createInjector (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4430:19)
        at doBootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1710:20)
        at bootstrap (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1731:12)
```

Here is the content of .yo-rc.json

```
{
 "generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
"baseName": "blog",
"packageName": "com.albertofaci.blog",
"packageFolder": "com/albertofaci/blog",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "session",
"hibernateCache": "no",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "no",
"databaseType": "mongodb",
"devDatabaseType": "mongodb",
"prodDatabaseType": "mongodb",
"searchEngine": "no",
"buildTool": "gradle",
"enableSocialSignIn": false,
"rememberMeKey": "94cf21b11aff8d8d4a9b9b3724834876b995e5b1",
"useSass": false,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
  "gatling"
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
  "en",
  "es"
]
}}
```

node version: v6.0.0

npm version: 3.8.7

java 8

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Might not be a solution but we recommend to use LTS version of Node. Also I'm surprised to read `gulp-tslint-log`, are you using typescript?

Comment: I was just using a fresh node and npm installation with jhipster out of the box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as the OP, I changed to use the LTS version of Node as Gaël Marziou suggested. This fixed the problem.

Comment: thanks guys, that did the trick. I still have some angular problems, but I'd ask that somewhere else

Comment: on arch linux installing the LTS version from aur solved the issue: yaourt -S nodejs-lts-argon

Comment: I also installed the LTS version on OS X via the installer https://nodejs.org/en/#download which solved the issue.